# Segmentation fault: 11 in basic single source C program

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am an absolute beginner is C, so bear with me.
I am getting a segmentation fault: 11 directly after I put my Name in When I run my code. When I compile it never has any errors so I am really not sure what I am doing wrong. I am on mac also if that affects anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char * name;
    char * pass;
} user;

void prompt(user u) {
    char passw;
    char name;
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    if (strncmp(u.name, &name, strlen(u.name)) == 1) {
        printf("Correct! Please input password:\n");
        scanf("%s", &passw);
        if (strncmp(u.pass, &passw, strlen(u.pass)) == 0) {
            printf("Congrats! you got in.\n");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    user me;
    me.name = "Me";
    me.pass = "1234";
    prompt(me);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are several problems with the code, like not checking the returned value from scanf() and only allocating a single char for 'name' the using a `%s` format specifier.   Note: always put a max length modifier on %s format specifiers where the modifier is one less that the available length of the input buffer to allow for the NUL byte that will be appended by scanf().  Otherwise the user will overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: these two lines: `    char name;    scanf("%s", &name);` should be similar to: `    char name[30];   if( 1 != scanf("%s", &name) ) { perror("scanf for name failed:)' exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`.   Similar considerations exist for the reading of the passw string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the variable type `name` and the corresponding format specifier. You defined it to be a `char`, but you use `%s` to scan the value. It causes a bound-overflow that creates [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make `name` an array, like

```
 char name[64] = {0};  //size is for demo
```

and the, use `scanf()` like

```
 scanf("%63s", name);
```

same goes for `passw`, also.

FWIW, `%s` is used to scan a *string*, whereas, to intake a single `char`, you need to use `%c` format specifier.

Also, you can consider having a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for `fgets()` as this is considered a safer alternative.

Comment: Better to use `fgets`.

Comment: But he is comparing with a string literal , new line character has to be removed then .

Comment: @ameyCU; That's not a difficult task.

Comment: @haccks nopes, you wrote that. :)